# How to have argv option in fish shell function?

Tags: macos, terminal, fish

I need to have my fish function accept option for an argv. 
Something like,

```
myProg <command> <options>
```

Currently i have the following function

```
function myProg
        java -jar "/Users/username/myProg/myprog-0.2.jar" "$argv"
 end
```

I need to send the following command from my terminal

```
myProg vm start
```

Can you please help with how to rewrite the function to accept the options?

Thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fish variables like `$argv` are arrays and when interpolated into a command should not be enclosed in double-quotes unless you want to concatenate the values into a single string. In other words just define your function like this:

```
function myProg
    java -jar "/Users/username/myProg/myprog-0.2.jar" $argv
end
```

Comment: It's worth noting that with the quotes, fish doesn't make them a single string, it actually puts quotes around each of the arguments, so, `myProg vm start` will run `java -jar "/path/thing.jar" "vm" "start"`.

Comment: No it doesn't. It turns them into a single string, with spaces between the list element. See e.g. `set list foo bar; printf "%s\n" "$list"`.

Comment: faho is correct, emma. I suspect you're thinking of the behavior of the `"$@"` construct in POSIX compatible shells. Fish does not support that because it doesn't need to given that it has saner variable interpolation semantics.